How Can I add an image asset to my front matter in Bootstrap 3
I want to add an image asset to my front matter for schema to pick up. Is there a way to do this?
When I add to CSS I use this:
background-image: url(asset_path("nfp-logo-opt-200.jpg"));

Not sure how to do the path in front matter.
I've not tried anything yet.
